# Alter table and modify column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to modify a particular column in a table and i use this but there is a red line under 
modify and 4. please help

```
ALTER TABLE COURSEINFO_TBL MODIFY 
COLUMN CRS_GP DECIMAL(4,1) NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE COURSEINFO_TBL 
ALTER COLUMN CRS_GP DECIMAL(4,1) NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go for

```
   ALTER TABLE COURSEINFO_TBL ALTER COLUMN CRS_GP DECIMAL(4,1) NOT NULL
```